# Get the Year and remaining days from two dates in WINFORM C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

I am trying to get the year(s) from two dates, and if the year(s) are not integer e.g. 2, 3 then I need to resolve the remaining days.

This is a rough code that I have so far:

```
DateTime inTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LblFirstDate.Text);
DateTime outTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LblSecondDate.Text);

double VTotalDay = outTime.Subtract(inTime).Days;

if (VTotalDay < 365)
{
    LblDays.Text = "Days: " + VTotalDay.ToString();
}
else
{
    double VOver365 = (outTime - inTime).Days / 365.25;
    LblDays.Text = "Years: " +  VOver365.ToString();
}
```

Entering these dates: ***7/11/2022, 6/29/2024*** will yield ***1.9685*** which is a over a year but under 2 years.

Most of the example I found only show Year, Month and days remaining.

I trying to get the remaining days from this. I do not need the month, just the days. E.g. 1 year xxx days.

Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thx

Comment: Create a variable that gets the value of `numOfDays % yearDays`, and if that value is bigger than 0 add it to `yearDays`

Comment: Whenever it comes to something like `remainingDays` you also have to take into account leapyears. Because The result will be differerent for `2022-07-11 -> 2024-06-29` or `2020-07-11 -> 2022-06-29`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [Aca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18099076/aca) suggestions and resolved the issue.

Here is the modified code:

```
            DateTime inTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LblFirstDate.Text);
            DateTime outTime = Convert.ToDateTime(LblSecondDate.Text);
            
            double VTotalDay = outTime.Subtract(inTime).Days;

            if (VTotalDay < 365)
            {
                LblYears.Text = "Days: " + VTotalDay.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                double VOver365 = (outTime - inTime).Days / 365.25;
                var days = (outTime - inTime).Days % 365.25;

                LblYears.Text = Math.Floor(VOver365).ToString() + " Years" + " " + (Math.Round(days, 0)).ToString() + " Days";
            }
```

If the total days are less then ***365*** it display the total days, if the total days are over ***365*** it will make the calculation to ***math.floor*** and display the Year from the variable ***VOver365***. It then ***Math.Round*** the remaining days from the variable ***days***.

For date range ***7/11/2022, 6/29/2024*** from this ***1.9685*** to
[image]

Comment: You have a small error (due to the *dumb* 365.25 value and rounding) that accumulates. Already with a starting date of `7/11/2004` you lose a day. If you need to be precise (or *consistent*), I suggest you add the [NodaTime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime/) NuGet, then you can write, e.g., `var inTime = new LocalDate(2004, 7, 11); var outTime = new LocalDate(2024, 6, 29); var period = Period.Between(inTime, outTime, PeriodUnits.Years | PeriodUnits.Days);` and you'll get the correct value in `period.Years` and `period.Days`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is take the floor of `VOver365` for the years and use the modulus operator to get the number of days.

```
var years = Math.Floor(VOver365);
var days = (outTime - inTime).Days % 365.25;
```